# User_Agent string in svn client tools

Tags: svn

we need to set our own custom user-agent string in svn client tools(svn.exe,svnmucc.exe,svnsync.exe,etc).
But we don't want to use dlls for this User-Agent String(but we use dlls for other operations). How can we set custom the user agent  string to executable itself(svn.exe,svnsync,...) while building the subversion sources.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The user-agent string is set in `ra_serf.h` See [this patch](http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2007-11/0678.shtml) which created this ability for you.